# Operating system not found after installing Debian

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I recently installed `Debian "Stretch" amd64` on an external HDD.

What I have done:

```
1. Created a 64GB ext4 partition for mount point /   .
2. Created a swap area. 
3. The rest is unallocated.
4. Chose to install as non UEFI.
5. Installed GRUB on external hard drive.
6. Finish & restart.
```

Key info:

```
1. External HDD is 1TB and not GPT.
2. I used Debian 9 amd64 installer.
3. My bios is set to legacy boot.
4. Booting to my external hard drive gives me "Operating system not found"
```

How can I solve this? Or

Answer (score 0):

The Errormessage is from the BIOS/UEFI not from GRUB?
Did you install grub to /dev/sdX (eg sda) or /dev/sdXY (eg sda1)?

- Remove any disk except the one you want to boot from.
  Still the same error?
- Boot from any linux live CD and reinstall grub to the disk using grub-install /dev/sdX
- try again booting
- tell us what's happening

Comment: Yes, but I just installed it with no problem. I choose `Yes` on installing `GRUB` on my main HDD but it prompted me what drive I should install it anyway. I booted my external hdd and GRUB shows up and Debian is booting fine

Comment: so does that mean your problem is solved? You are allowed to answer your question yourself...